# Unable to resolve symlink

Tags: clearcase

When updating my clearcase (snapshot) view I get the following symlink errors:

> Unable to resolve symlink
> "setups.cmd". The symlink
> target will not be loaded.
>
> Unable to resolve symlink "setup.sh".
> The symlink target will not be loaded.
>
> Unable to resolve symlink
> "setupwithdomain.doc". The
> symlink target will not be loaded.

What do I do or tell my admin to do to get rid of this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Windows? And with which ClearCase version

There is this [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21221086), which explains why attempts to create an IBM Rational ClearCase symbolic link on Microsoft® Windows in ClearCase Explorer from a snapshot view **fails when the snapshot view root is created with a lower case drive letter**.
But that would only be for CC2003.

[This thread mentions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=91650) a similar issue:

> We have had problems resolving symlinks when loading snapshot views.
>   It appears that the resolution of the pathname to the linked file is case sensitive.
>   The solution for us was to ensure that all symlinks used the correct case for the pathname to the linked file.

Comment: J:\>cleartool -version
ClearCase version 7.1.0.00 (Tue Nov 11 00:18:47 EST 2008) (7.1.D081110)
@(#) MVFS version 7.1.0.0 (Mon Oct 27 13:15:03 2008)
cleartool                         7.1.0.0 (Tue Oct 28 02:02:49 2008)
db_server                         7.1.0.0 (Tue Oct 28 02:45:38 2008)
VOB database schema version: 54

Comment: @oluies: ok. And where those that symlink is supposed to point to?