# ClearCase Symbolick Link Issue

Tags: clearcase, vob

I have created a symbolic link for `folder1` to make it available in `vob2\rootdir` from `vob1\rootdir`.
And I labeled the whole directory `folder1` recursively in `vob1`.
But when I modified the configspec of dynamic view to load `folder1`, it was loaded under `vob1`; But I couldn't see that folder in `vob2\rootdir`. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't modify a config spec to *load* anything in a **[dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)**: you only modify selection rules, there is no load rules (as opposed to snapshot view).

If you were actually using a snapshot view (with a path different from `M:\` or `/views`), then beware of [symlink resolution issue like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3941746/6309).

Finally, if your config spec doesn't select `vob2/rootdir`, or if it doesn't select the version which recorded the symlink, you wouldn't be able to see said symlink.
That means, labelling vob1/folder1 isn't enough: you need to make sure that:

- `/vob2` is labelled
- `/vobs2/rootdir` is labelled as well

In other words, the *parent* folders of your final selection target (target being '`/vobs/rootdir/folder1`) must be selected.